# How to retrieve 'repository root' id/children from CMIS repository?

Tags: alfresco, cmis, opencmis

I am using the [openCMIS](https://chemistry.apache.org/java/opencmis.html) library against a cmis 1.0 compliant server and I noticed that whenever I call getRepositories on the server (an alfresco v3.2 & v5.0 server) I only receive a list with one repository as opposed to what I was expecting, i.e. the list of roots on the server. How do I retrieve the list of repository roots using the opencmis library? 
**EDIT**
I inappropriately phrased the question so I will explain better.
What I would like to do is to be able to get the actual **`repository root id`**(i.e. store_root in alfresco for instance) **NOT** the **`root folder id`** , such that I can leverage that against the api to retrieve it's direct children i.e. objects at the same hierarchical level as root folder (**Company Home** in alfresco)

Comment: witch language you use ?!?

Comment: @YagamiLight I'm working with Java. I actually need to get the nodeRef or the 'store_root' object

Comment: do you want to get the children of any repository ?!?

Comment: The main `StoreRef` objects are wellknown, just do something like `StoreRef storeRef = new StoreRef(StoreRef.PROTOCOL_WORKSPACE, "SpacesStore");` in Java and you're done, no CMIS needed!

Comment: @Gagravarr I am restricted to using the opencmis library as per dictated by project specific requirements; as I am working on generic cmis accessor tool. I have been using alfresco as a test cmis only because that's what I am familiar with for the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alfresco only has one repository, so what you are seeing is correct.

To understand how to get the root folder (which is Company Home), then how to get the root folder's children, see [here](https://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/samples/retrieve-objects/index.html).

Comment: AAh you're right. I assumed all the other objects residing at the same level as company home were repository roots, whereas what I actually need is to be able to get the store_Root object.

Answer (score 1):

worked fine for me test it : 
first you have to create a session and connect it with this :

```
private static Session getSession(String serverUrl, String username, String password) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put(SessionParameter.USER, username);
    params.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, password);
    params.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, serverUrl);
    params.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());
    List<Repository> repos = sessionFactory.getRepositories(params);
    if (repos.isEmpty()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Server has no repositories!");
    }
    return repos.get(0).createSession();
}
```

after that only use this

```
Folder folder = session.getRootFolder();
```

hope that helped you

Comment: I edited the question for better clarity. I can already get the root folder id but not repo root id which is what I need.

Comment: any feedback about it ?!?

Comment: It would seem it is not possible to get the store_root object itself