# cmis or web scripts use?

Tags: alfresco, cmis, alfresco-webscripts

I want to build a JavaEE GED application using alfresco and activiti Workflow engine which  manages and monitors the mail of an organization (Letter, Fax, mail etc.). Since I am new with alfresco I want to know the best way to communicate with alfresco in my case : the use of CMIS or web scripts (I'm building a third-party application  ) .

Comment: you have two solution to do something like this [Rest API](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/alfresco-sdk-tutorials-using-rest-api-explorer.html) and [Apache Chimestery](https://chemistry.apache.org/java/opencmis.html) tell me if you need more informations

Comment: ok,thank you Mr Yagami just one question why you didn't advice me to just use web scripts

Comment: because in your case (using your technology) it will be better for you to use Apache Chimestery and i will help you to build such a thing like that

Comment: I've done something like that (it's pretty the same) and i can give you advice about it and answer about so many question : i will wright an answer explaining why if you want

Comment: i'll be so thankful if you do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest two solutions using [Using the REST API](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/alfresco-sdk-tutorials-using-rest-api-explorer.html) or CMIS with a library like [Apache Chemistry](https://chemistry.apache.org/java/opencmis.html)

Apache Chemistry is very well documented and you can find good pointers on the official website for pretty much any thing you would want to do !

If you want to get a session from your Alfresco Repository for example follow this post : [How to retrieve 'repository root' id/children from CMIS repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39230517/how-to-retrieve-repository-root-id-children-from-cmis-repository/39249385#39249385)

Alternatively, you can find a lot of resources around for interacting with alfresco using REST (either the new REST API, or old restful endpoints). Check the [platform integrations portal](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/dev-platform-integrations.html) from the official docs, it would be a very good starting point.

Comment: I will edit my answer to make it better feel free to ask for more and why not upvote it

Comment: did you choose a path to follow ?!?

Comment: I think as my first ECM application choosing CMIS is the best choice

Comment: Yes it is a good descision it will be my pleaser to help you to build such a thing like that